# Jquery tagsinput not creating tags automatically on pasting input

Tags: jquery, tags, paste, eventtrigger, jquery-tags-input

I'm using jquery.tagsinput and would like to be able to paste a list of email addresses separated by comma or space. Using something like this https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/issues/22 but it doesn't add them until I press Enter - Tried triggering keypress Enter event but it doesn't work. No luck with blur event either (shown below). Any ideas?

The Flat-UI tags are based on this library and I'm trying to achieve a very similar behaviour.

```
var tidyTags = function(e) {
  var tags = (e.tags).split(/[ ,]+/);
  var target = $(e.target);

  for (var i = 0, z = tags.length; i<z; i++) {
      var tag = $.trim(tags[i]);
      if (!target.tagExist(tag)) {
          target.addTag(tag);
      }
  }
  $('#' + target[0].id + '_tag').trigger('focus');

  //This doesn't work.
  target.blur();

};

$("#tagsinput").tagsInput({
    onAddTag : function(tag){
      if(tag.indexOf(',') > 0) {
          tidyTags({target: '#tagsinput', tags : tag});
      }
    },
});
```

Comment: so how you want it?? As soon as you paste you want to create tags??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes as soon as I paste it, right now it doesn't create the tags until I hit Enter or click out of the input

Comment: ok. See right now the basic functionality of the `tagsinput` is to create tag when you either focus out or click enter!! Even if you hit space it will not create `tags`!! Have you noticed that??

Comment: Yeah in this case, I've added split(/[ ,]+/) to take care of that

Comment: The method `onAddTag` will itself be called once you either `blur` out of `textbox` or when you hit `enter`! So Its of no use!! You need something like key press event for `tagsinput`!!

Comment: Oh you're right! Thanks for pointing it out! :) However, I'm unable to trigger blur or enter on detecting paste as well :( I think I'm targeting the wrong element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok finally figured out the solution:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1vfynL34/2/)**

Just add a listener to your `textbox` while pasting and do not set `onAddTag` during initialization and just give it a simple call as below:

```
$("#tagsinput").tagsInput();//Initialization

$("#tagsinput_tag").on('paste',function(e){
    var element=this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var text = $(element).val();
        var target=$("#tagsinput");
        var tags = (text).split(/[ ,]+/);
        for (var i = 0, z = tags.length; i<z; i++) {
              var tag = $.trim(tags[i]);
              if (!target.tagExist(tag)) {
                    target.addTag(tag);
              }
              else
              {
                  $("#tagsinput_tag").val('');
              }
         }
    }, 0);
});
```

> **Some points to note:**
>
> - `paste` method will only fire if text is selected in Firefox
> - `tagsinput` will hide your `#tagsinput` textbox and adds its own `input` textbox and thus you need to call `paste` event on `#tagsinput_tag` textbox and the structure of the element will be as shown in below image:[image: Structure image]

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Is it at all possible to let the width and height of the whole box be defined by my personal css? Like a % of a flex width?

Comment: @NicolasV Yes it is possible.. It'll be easy if you know the proper structure of the element in `DOM`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ah like that. I wish there was an option for it in the settings! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks a lot for this inspiring solution !**

I had some issues with the code above. I was using [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) and didn't want to access the elements by ID.

Here is what worked for me in a [directive](/questions/tagged/directive) declaration, in case someone might be insterested :

```
link: function(scope, el, attr){

    /* initializing element */
    var $el = angular.element(el);
    $el.tagsinput({...}); //<-- initialize as desired

    /* getting the "_tag" input  */
    var $elTag = $el.tagsinput('input');

    /* attaching event to "_tag" input */
    $elTag.on('paste', function (e) {
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(element).val();
            var target = $el;
            $elTag.val(''); // <--- removes the pasted value containing the ","
            var tags = (text).split(/[ ,]+/);
            for (var i = 0, z = tags.length; i < z; i++) {
                var tag = $.trim(tags[i]);
                if(target.tagsinput('items').indexOf(tag) < 0){ // <-- I got "'tagExist' not a function" error
                    target.tagsinput('add',tag);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should import this files https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/tree/master/src

This is our script code.

```
 $(function () {
        $("#EditorInputs").val($("#Editors").val());
        $('#EditorInputs').tagsInput({
            'height': '50px',
            'width': 'auto',
            'defaultText': 'Editor',
            'removeWithBackspace': true,
            'delimiter': [','],
            'onChange': function () {
                $("#Editors").val($('#EditorInputs').val());
            }
        });
    });
```

if you are using MVC

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Editors, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Editors)
                <input id="EditorInputs" value="" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Editors, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Output]